# Variable global defined in a function is showing undefined when called outside the function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have defined a function by using let and then created a function.
This function send a post request to an api and get data in json format. In this function I have used a variable and set it equal to the value of the response.

when I use this function all works fine.
whenI use this variable outside the function then I get undefined value''

below is my code

```
var request = require("request");

let conkey = 'Some Value', //varialble for consumer_key
consec = 'Some Value', //varialble for  consumer_secret
tkn = 'Some Value', //varialble for token
tknsec = 'Some Value',
value;


function myFunction() {
request.post('someurl', {
    oauth: {
        consumer_key: conkey,
        consumer_secret: consec,
        token: tkn,
        token_secret: tknsec
    },body: {"skillIds": [some value]
},json: true}, function (err, res, body) {
    if (err) throw new Error(err);
    value = body.sonething.something;
    console.log(value);  ////THIS WORKS FINE
});
};

myFunction();
console.log(value);  ////This prints Undefined
```

Comment: And I'd imagine that you're getting `undefined` in console **before** the one that works. You may want to read this: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Could you post code that actually reproduces the issue?

Answer (score 1):

This occurs because `request.post` is an asynchronous action. Which means it is going to be completed **eventually** but not immediately. That is also why `request.post` accepts a function, which is known as the callback function.

`function (err, res, body) { ... }` will be called only when the request finishes.

Let's walk through your code in order... it will first:

1 - Create your variables.

2 - Define `myFunction`

3 - Calls `myFunction`. `myFunction` will call on `request.post`. However `request.post` is asynchronous. This means it will return immediately before it has the result. `myFunction` now exits.

4 - `console.log(value);` is now called, but at this point of time, `value` is undefined.

5 - When the request is completed, `function (err, res, body)` (defined in the `request.post` call) will execute

```
value = body.sonething.something;
console.log(value);
```

And `value` here will now be defined.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use js’s **fetch api**, which is promise based, it will help you solve your issue.
Or some other side libraries, such as **axios**.

The problem is that your code doesn’t wait for request to be received and console.logs before your response would change Value’s “value”. That’s why I think you get undefined.

Comment: This isn't a scoping issue. It's an asynchronous issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your answers.
I was able to get over the issue by creating an empty object outside the function and with in function I inserted the values in the empty object.